# How to elegantly recover from network failure & repeat request to different endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a few servers that I make REST requests to from my program. They will all have the same response to a particular request.

I accept one `ip` as argument and make my requests to that server. If I wish to now accept a `List<ip>`, how do I elegantly switch to the next server in the list when one fails? Looping through the list on every network call seems silly.

Unfortunately I cannot make a REST call with the catch-repeat_to_next_server extracted to one function that accepts an HttpClient with the rest of the request because I'm using a 3rd part SDK to talk to the servers and every request is a chain of method calls.

I can't do this (pseudo-code):

```
def doRequest(HttpClient client)
    for ip in list_of_ips:
        try:
            client.host = ip
            return client.execute()
        catch exp:
            // move failed ip to end of list or something

        throw "None of them worked"

HttpClient c
c.method = "GET /api/employees"
doRequest(c)
c.method = "GET /api/department/:id"
doRequest(c)
```

Are there any standard ways to solve this in clean way?

I'm using Java and   Spring so I am constrained by static typing but may have some sort of Spring annotation magic that I can use that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

How you are making the REST call is not important.
Your psuedo code should be correct even if you need to make a million method calls per REST call.

```
for ip in ip_list
    do_stuff_to_make_the_rest_call
    perhaps_note_the_ip_that_was_used
    indicate_success
    break_out_of_for_loop
  catch some_exception
    perhaps_note_the_ip_that_failed
end for

if !success
  do all_ip_failed_stuff.


procedure do_stuff_to_make_the_rest_call
   make a million method calls to get one REST call attempt.
```